# Add value to :params[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What i have: (Action in Controller)

```
def create
  @test = Test.new(params[:test])
  @test.save

  devicefiles = params[:devicefiles]
  if devicefiles != nil
    devicefiles.each do |attrs|
      devicenote = Testdevicenote.new(attrs, :test_id => @test.id)
      devicenote.save
    end
  end

end
```

This controller action does not show any error message and is rendering the view, but :test_id is not being saved in the database. How can i solve this?

Comment: Try raising the params to see if there is anything in params[:test]. Do this by adding `raise params[:test].inspect` after def create

Comment: @Igrabes params[:test] is not nil and Test is being saved correctly. Also Testdevicenote is being saved, but the column :test_id is always NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Ok whoops, I see it now...

Models only take one hash on initialize, not 2.

```
Testobjectnote.new(attrs.merge(:test_id => @test.id))
```

---

In short no one here has any clue, because that's not enough information.  We dont know how your models are setup.

But when debugging models that "won't save" it's often good to use the bang version `save`, `save!`.  `save` returns `true` or `false` letting you know if it was able to save the record. But `save!` will raise exceptions when the model can't be saved, and the exception will tell you why.

That exception will likely tell you why the record is not being saved.

---

Also, its usually better to use the associations, rather than manage the ids yourself.

```
def create
  @test = Test.new(params[:test])

  if params[:devicefiles]
    params[:devicefiles].each do |attrs|
      @test.testdevicenotes << Testdevicenotes(attrs)
    end
  end

  @test.save
end
```

Comment: Why would my models matter? As stated everything is being saved, just the column `test_id` in each Testdevicenote is always NULL. So it seems this is some kind of syntax mistake.

Comment: Actually, my bad, you are kind of right.  See my edit.  I still don't recommend doing it this way though.  Rails associations are the coolest thing ever, and you should use the hell out of them.

Comment: Works, thanks alot! But i think u mean `merge` not `marge`. Also thanks for the association tip.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say because you didn't post your view with the form that is posting to the create action,  but if it's a typical Rails form,  it should probably look like:

```
def create
  @test = Test.new(params[:test])
  @test.save

  devicefiles = params[:test][:devicefiles]
  if devicefiles != nil
    devicefiles.each do |attrs|
      devicenote = Testdevicenote.new(attrs, :test_id => @test.id)
      devicenote.save
    end
  end

  objectfiles = params[:test][:objectfiles]
  if objectfiles != nil
    objectfiles.each do |attrs|
      objectnote = Testobjectnote.new(attrs, :test_id => @test.id)
      objectnote.save
    end
  end
end
```

This assumes that :devicefiles and :objectfiles are inside the form :test

Comment: I do not have any form. I just have the submitted hashes and they work as intended. Only my :test_id column in each Testdevicenote is always NULL.